# SEO Friendly URL's with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Had a look around before posting this and couldn't find anything that matched with my specific problem.

On my website, I prefer to have my URL's without .php in them, so I have that set up in in my .htaccess file and it works perfectly. At the moment I have a page on my site called "Albums", that are the top albums of the year currently. However, I'd like to also do it for next year and so on. Now, I can do it as albums?date=2017, but that looks ugly. I'm wanting to do it as example.com/albums/2017, as it looks a lot nicer and it's more SEO Friendly.

What I have in my HTACCESS is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove PHP from file names
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

# Redirect albums.php?date=2017 to albums/2017
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/albums\?date=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /albums/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^albums/([0-9]+)$ /albums?date=$1 [L]


Options -Indexes

# Error Document Redirects
ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/errors/403
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/errors/404
```

albums.php?date=2017 works without the the redirects, but when I put the redirects in, it sends you to /albums/2017, but doesn't show anything on the page. If I remove my "Remove PHP from file names" redirections, it does show the information on the page. So obviously I've worked out that the error is caused due to the "Remove PHP from file names" section of the file, I'm just not sure how to fix it.

I'm not hugely knowledgeable with .htaccess and the RewriteEngine, only know enough or very basic things, so apologies if this looks horrendous. I've had a look to try and make sure that I've not made a duplication question, but sorry if I have,

Comment: Thanks to whoever downvoted this without explaining why it was downvoted. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
# Redirect albums.php?date=2017 to albums/2017
RewriteRule ^albums/([^/]*)$ /albums?date=$1 [L]

# Remove PHP from file names
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
# removed .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ $1.php

# you can directly use album/(date) in your url using this rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ $1.php?date=$2
```

Comment: albums?date=2017 works, but when you go to albums/2017, it just shows a 404 saying the file cannot be found.

Comment: okay i mean when you call albums.php?date=2017 it is working with php extension or not

Comment: album.php, just a normal php page